# seperating parts

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

If I have an object , say a robot.  is there a way to slice through the parts and make those separate objects ? say separating the hands from the arm. At the moment the whole this in just one part

Comment: if each part is already a separate mesh it will be easy (select a mesh with L and separate with P). If the body is made of one mesh it will be more complicate to separate each part, you'll need to select some edge loops and rip (V)

Comment: I've tried that but I get errors. I have had a go at trying that with a simple cube and I am able to use the RIP tool but when I go into object mode it still shows as one object albeit in 2 pieces. I wanted them to be treated as two objects so that they can be animated.

Comment: if they are 2 separate objects, first remove the Armature modifier if you they ever have one. Now you need to parent them to their own bone: Select the object, shift select the armature, switch to Pose mode, select the bone you want, then Ctrl P > Bone

Comment: Figured it out. This is what I did. Select the robot, right click and convert to mesh. Then go into wire frame view and then edit mode. Select what you like to separate and press  P and choose the selection option. Now go into object mode and move the object as you normally would.